# MySQL regexp search JSON array

Tags: mysql, regex

I am storing json data to one of the fields in a table and I am having trouble using REGEXP to return the correct entry
Basically, it matches other attributes in the JSON object, that it should not

Sample JSON

```
    {
  "data": {
    "en": {
      "containers": [
        {
          "id": 1441530944931,
          "template": "12",
          "columns": {
            "column1": [
              "144",
              "145",
              "148"
            ],
            "column2":[
                "135",
                "148",
                "234"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "left": "152",
      "right": "151"
    },

  }
}
```

Now, I would like to search the columns array against a specific value (ie 148)

Right now I have the below query

```
WHERE (w.`_attrs` REGEXP '"column[0-9]":.*\\[.*"148".*\\]'
```

which works just fine
However, if I change the value from 148 to 152 or 151, it also works
For some reason the query matches the attribute **left** and **right** as well, but this is not desirable

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that based on the sample data given, if you match on `152` it will return positive?

Comment: Correct. It will match 151 as well. Basically, it will match any key, whose value is enclosed with "".

Comment: It is as if it skips entirely the "column[0-9]":. part

Comment: You might consider storing the column values separately (json-decoded, that is) and check against that field.

Comment: Your wildcards `.*` need to explicitly *exclude* brackets, e.g. `[^\\[]*`.  But I can't help feeling you've made some poor design decisions here, insofar as this filter is not sargable... if you're going to use a *relational database*, why don't you store *relational data* (i.e. normalise this JSON!); otherwise, a document storage (NoSQL) database might be more suitable?

Comment: @eggyal: Thanks for the help. Modified it to '"column[0-9]"\\:.*\\[[^\\[]*"148"[^\\[]*\\]' and it now works. Regarding the poor design you mention. It is easy for someone to say something like that, based on the limited description I have given, If the JSON I store, was the same for each row, I would have normalized it, but it is not. And the JSON I posted is just an extract of the full object.

Comment: @Thomas: That only makes it sounds even less suited to an RDBMS.  Take a look at how some document-based NoSQL databases (e.g. MongoDB) handle JSON—the entire contents would be indexed and easily searchable without relying on error-prone (and extremely slow) pattern-based string matching.

Answer (score 0):

Or...  Switch to MariaDB 10 and index the components of the JSON.